# How can I remove icons from the GNOME Shell panel?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, icons

I tried to use the `gmenu-simple` editor, but it said it can't find it. It's just for a good look.

Comment: Try the package `alacarte`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution taken from the [arch-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Manually_editing_the_GNOME_panel_script):

When doing a GNOME install, some unwanted icons might appear in the panel. To remove the icons, edit the GNOME panel script.

> For example, to remove the universal access icon. Remove `a11y` from
>   the AREA_ORDER line and comment out the `a11y` line in
>   `AREA_SHELL_IMPLEMENTATION`
>
> ```
> /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js
>
> const STANDARD_STATUS_AREA_ORDER = ['ally', 'keyboard', 'volume', 'network', 'bluetooth', 'battery', 'userMenu'];
> const STANDARD_STATUS_AREA_SHELL_IMPLEMENTATION = {
>     'a11y': imports.ui.status.accessibility.ATIndicator
>     'volume': imports.ui.status.volume.Indicator,
>     'battery': imports.ui.status.power.Indicator,
>     'keyboard': imports.ui.status.keyboard.XKBIndicator,
>     'userMenu': imports.ui.userMenu.UserMenuButton
> };
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js
>
> const STANDARD_STATUS_AREA_ORDER = ['keyboard', 'volume', 'network', 'bluetooth' 'battery', 'userMenu'];
> const STANDARD_STATUS_AREA_SHELL_IMPLEMENTATION = {
>     //'a11y': imports.ui.status.accessibility.ATIndicator
>     'volume': imports.ui.status.volume.Indicator,
>     'battery': imports.ui.status.power.Indicator,
>     'keyboard': imports.ui.status.keyboard.XKBIndicator,
>     'userMenu': imports.ui.userMenu.UserMenuButton
> };
> ```
>
> save your results and restart the shell to see results:
>
> ```
> Alt+F2
> r
> Enter
> ```

I am using this right now and it works with my gnome-shell!

Comment: It may be better to use the Evil extension however, because every update to these scripts will undo the work.  Only a version update will require any modification to extensions.

Answer (score 0):

.. one simple task -

Start Terminal and type in "sudo nautilus" ( without quotes )

Now, go to usr/share/applications/ ( click File System to see usr folder )..

You'll see a whole bunch of apps, whichever you don't want to see in the Gnome panel you drag it from there to another place ( whether it's desktop, folder etc.. do NOT remove it )..

Will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + Rightclick

To open a menu.